# Detecting a cycle in an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, function, cycle

I'm running a simple script which puts an integer through the [formula of the Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) and adds the output of each step into an array.

I want to use a function to detect if there's a cycle in the array, using [Floyd's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Algorithms). And though I feel like I'm not doing a bad job, I don't seem to get it right. At this moment I'm getting the error `Trying to get property 'next' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\educom\week3\functions.php on line 12`

See my code below. Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

```
    include("functions.php");

    $n = $_POST['number'];
    $step = 0;
    $reeks1 = array();
    $cycle = 0;
    echo "Your entry is: ". $n ."<br><br>";


    while($n!==1 && $cycle==0){
        $cycle = detect_cycle(array($reeks1));
            if($n % 2 == 0){
                $n = $n / 2;
                array_push($reeks1, "$n");
                $step++;
                echo $step .": ". $n ."<br>";
            }else{
                $n = ($n * 3) + 1;
                array_push($reeks1, "$n");
                $step++;
                echo $step .": ". $n ."<br>";
            }
        }
```

functions.php:

```
function detect_cycle($node){
    if ($node==NULL){
        return FALSE;
    }
    $turtle = $node;
    $rabbit = $node->next;
    while($rabbit != NULL){
        if($rabbit === $turtle){
            return TRUE;
        }elseif($rabbit->next == NULL){
            return FALSE;
        }else{
            $turtle = $turtle->next;
            $rabbit = $rabbit->next->next;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: What is in your `$node`?

Comment: You can't just use `->next` to fetch the next item in an array.

Comment: when you use -> next php thinks you are referring to a property from a object. if you want you can use $node[0] or $node[1]

Comment: The script adds up to infinite items into the array. I can't hardcode which index to fetch from if I don't know how many there are. Isn't there a way to fetch the next item in an array?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. IMPORTANT I don't know is this according to your theory. but it won't give you errors if you use like this.

```
function detect_cycle($node){
    if ($node==NULL){
        return FALSE;
    }
    $turtle = $node;
    $rabbit = $node[0];
    while($rabbit != NULL){
        if($rabbit === $turtle){
            return TRUE;
        }elseif($rabbit[0] == NULL){
            return FALSE;
        }else{
            $turtle = $turtle[0]; // use the number of the element key starting from 0
            $rabbit = $rabbit[0][1];
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```